# How to translate partial/variable in partial in OctoberCMS with rainlab.translate plug-in?

Tags: php, octobercms

Just started using OcteberCMS and now trying to figure out how to translate with rainlab.translate plug-in  partial (no, I can't use here {{ ''|_ }} for some reason).

For example, code of layout:

```
{% partial "footer" %}
```

I have 2 files in "partials" dir:

footer.htm and footer.fr.htm

but always footer.htm including, but not footer.fr.htm when I'm switch language to fr.

Or maybe is there some way to pass translated variable to partial?

```
{% partial "sidebar-contacts" city="Vancouver" country="Canada" %}
```

<strike>{% partial "sidebar-contacts" city="{{ 'Vancouver'|_ }}" country="Canada" %}</strike>

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple: just pipe variable |_ into translate plug-in like this:

```
{% partial "sidebar-contacts" city="Vancouver" country="Canada" %}
```

In file sidebar-contacts:

```
<div class="sidebar-contacts">
  {{ city|_ }}, {{ country|_ }}
</div>
```